# FOR Loop link generating by limits

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

How to generate links? For example I want to create 10 links starting from page/5 and generate 10 link dynamically - it seems skip first 5 and generate from link 5 to 15 e.g.

page/5, page/6, page/7, to page/15

```
$numOfPages = 10;
$startfrom = 5;
$pages = [];

for ($i = $startfrom; $i <= $numOfPages; $i++) {
$pages[] = 'page/' . $i;
}
```

Not working if work if $startfrom grater than $numOfPages

Comment: you need to add a language tag. What Pages are you talking about? Sorry, we don't share your brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$startfrom is an offset, so you need to loop from that offset to the offset+the number of pages you want to have:

```
for ($i = $startfrom; $i < $startfrom+$numOfPages; $i++) {
```

Of you can do the addition inside the loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numOfPages; $i++) {
  $pages[] = 'page/' . ($i + $startfrom)
}
```

But since you probably have a maximum number of pages, which may not be a multiple of 5 of 10, I'd introduce an extra variable and determine the end of the loop before actually looping (using [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)). That way, the loop itself and the code in it is nice and simple:

```
$totalPages = 28; 
$pagesToShow = 10;
$startFrom = 5;

$loopTo = min($startFrom + $pagesToShow - 1, $totalpages);

for ($i = $startFrom; $i <= $loopTo; $i++) {
  $pages[] = 'page/' . $i;
}
```

Comment: Dear @golezTrol thanks for reply, in the result i have one extra link if i wan to get 5 links then it will return 6 can i replace $i <= $startfrom+$numOfPages into $i < $startfrom+$numOfPages

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake because usually these kind of iterations start at 0, not 1. In the first loop, you can change it to `<`. The second loop, I think, is already correct. In the last snippet, it's better to subtract 1 in the calculation of `$loopTo`, otherwise, you'll miss the last page in the output. I've changed all snippets accordingly.